# Should I use SQL or Core Data?

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios5

I'm creating an iPhone app that will have a preloaded set of locations with Lat/Long, currently sqlite DB.  I will be calculating the distance of those locations from the users current location and display that in a TableView sorted by distance.

Should I just use the sqlite DB or should I use Core Data?

If I use Core Data, how do I get my initial DB loaded?

Are there any good Core Data tutorials that show how to preload a DB vs all user entry from the app, as my app will have no user entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's philosophy.

If you think in terms of a database, and you design from a data-oriented point of view, then straight sqlite is probably your best choice.  There's extra complexity in Core Data but its big benefit is that it accommodates people who think of a program in terms of objects and want some of those objects to stay around between runs of the code.

Comment: I was thinking Core Data would be less complex, but hey thats why we ask questions.  If I'm talking about 500 entries or less am I making things more complicated by even using sqlite?

Comment: When I said more complex, I was thinking in terms of set-up and structure mostly.  There's a separate design tool for the Core Data entities, with attributes you need to figure out.  There are more management objects with rules about how they can or can't behave in threads.  But, again, if you think in objects, the runtime use of it may be easier.  As for whether to use a DB...I don't know; a DB (or Core Data) has an advantage when handling relationships, which sounds like something you don't need.

Comment: You are exactly right.  Every example I have seen about Core Data is using relationships, which I don't need at this point.  I'm familiar with setting up the entities and attributes of Core Data, but can you preload data that ships with the app?  Are there any good tutorials about how to do that?

Comment: You can have code that detects if it's a first run of the program and builds your data model if that's true.  You can also write a "data loader" program using the same model as the real project, run it locally, and copy its output into your project while building.  What I understand you **can't** do is take a simple sqlite database and ask Core Data to use it.